# Extra weight values in neural network (nnet for R package)

Tags: r, neural-network

I'm attempting to reverse engineer in Excel how the nnet package works using some simple input data. Here's the steps I've taken

1. Import dummy data:`test <- read.csv('dataScaled.csv',header=TRUE,sep = ",")`
2. Train the network:
   `anntrain <- nnet(Price ~ Sqft + Bedrooms + Bathrooms,test[1:650,],size=2, maxit=5000,linout=TRUE)`
3. Grab the weights of the ANN:
   `anntrain$wts`
   This outputs:

   [1] -2.12443010  6.68900321  0.85338018 -0.73329823 -3.95336239  7.91917321
    [7] -5.38893137  4.05941771 -0.02062346  0.26584364  0.32881035
4. Grab fitted values of trained network:
   `anntrain$fitted.values`
   This outputs what I believe to be the scaled Price predictions of the trained network for each of the 650 transactions I trained it on above.
5. Prove out the fitted values by recalculating using the above weights using the sigmoid function.

My confusion is that it outputs 11 weight values. If I only have 3 inputs, 2 hidden nodes and 1 output, shouldn't that equate to only 8 weights? What are the 3 extra weights for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bias in every layer ([Why use a bias/threshold?](ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/FAQ2.html#A_bias)). A bias is like a node that always gives you the input 1. Thus you have (3+1)*2+(2+1)*1 = 11 weights.